# how to initialize database with code first in simple membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first, simplemembership

I want to customize my user profile table any how.Its my primary need so i changed the `usersContext Dbcontext` to something like this:

```
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfiles")]
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.PostComments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
        this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string AvatarExt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostComment> PostComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and my `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs` class looks something like this:

```
   private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
```

The problem which I am facing is it is creating two `userProfile` tables; one is in singular form i.e `UserProfile` and the other in plural form i.e with name `UserProfiles` table.**
1. I want to initialize simple membership table for authentication in database so that I can use them for login and registration purposes.
2. Should I have to use two dbcontext in my solution file.one for initialising simple membership related tables and then with other `Dbcontext`, I should customize my database to have more tables with the help of migrations.
3. If I use two `dbContext`, in that case also, I would have to customize user profile table. So, how should I craft the code so that only one UserProfiles table get created in database with `usersDbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

what approach you are using in your other modules of project other than membership?? Db - First or Code-First if you are using DB-First approach then then definitely there will be two connection string one for edmx data entity and one is for membership connections.